# Level Sets Questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1) In the following link, question 1:
http://mathquest.carroll.edu/libraries/MVC.student.14.01.pdf

Is it true that both partial derivatives are negative ? If so, can someone help me find an example of a contour plot with $f_x<0 , f_y>0$ in one of the points ? I just want to verify

2) In the following (question 4, with $t=1$ instead of 2 ):
http://mathquest.carroll.edu/libraries/MVC.student.14.06.pdf

At $t=1$ i think that the derivative is positive... this is because the $x'(1)=0 ,y'(1)>0$ and $  z_y(3,0)  > 0 $ .. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To avoid future link rot, please copy down as much of the relevant information as possible into your question. At minimum, take a screenshot and include it as an image in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I could just make a guess of the function in part one. I could just imagine and so the following function may help us to find out what exactly happens in that point.

$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+(y-2)$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since I wrote my thoughts, can you please refer to them and help me understand my mistakes ? (or, verify my answers ? )

Comment: @czash: It seems to me that you are right. The behavior of $f(x,y)$ at that point shows that. Sorry, I feel that behavior but cannot show the real without a blackboard.

Comment: @Babak S.:▒█wOW█▒$\Large{+}$▒██Your█work█is█really█great██▓▒(◕‿◕)▒▓██¥ѺṲℝ▒₩ϴℝḲ▒Їϟ▒ℝℰѦḺℒУ▒Ḡℜ€Ѧ✝██▓▒

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks a lot ! (Just to make sure:  you think my answer is correct,right ?  I couldn't understand the last sentence you wrote)

Comment: @czash: Sorry for the delay. Yes you did it right.

Comment: Beautiful graph. I see @flashdesign2550 is very *creative* & *artistic* with comments ;-)

Comment: @amWhy:$\Large{☂}{ᖺ}{ᗩ}{ﬡ}{Ḱ}$ Ꭹᗝ⋒ ᐯᙓᖇᎩ ᙢᘎᑕᖺ ✿(>‿◠)✿